# How to convert to Hungarian on Python

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I have an issue where I cannot encode values to proper text.
Couple of examples in array. These are should be Hungarian language as result:

```
['Sz?lvavölgy sét?ny', 'Magas ?t', 'Széchenyi Istv?n utca']
```

example of python code:

```
cases = ['Sz?lvavölgy sét?ny', 'Magas ?t', 'Széchenyi Istv?n utca']
[print(item.encode('latin').decode('utf8')) for item in cases]
```

I get traceback:
[image]

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code? and what the desired output should be? And what/where does your input come from? And do you happen to know what your local regions locale is? `ISO-8859-15`?

Comment: I have added example of the python code

Comment: Good, but what's the desired output? I don't see any examples. And `UTF-8` can not encode or decode these characters as they are outside of the defined character range.

Comment: as a output I want to receive the same values but on right Hungarian language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you fool around with `encode` and `decode` methods?

```
cases = ['Szílvavölgy sétány', 'Magas Út', 'Széchenyi István utca']
print('cases =', cases)
print('items =')
[print(item) for item in cases]
```

**Output**:

```
D:\Python\SO3\61959636.py
```

> ```
> cases = ['Szílvavölgy sétány', 'Magas Út', 'Széchenyi István utca']
> items =
> Szílvavölgy sétány
> Magas Út
> Széchenyi István utca
> ```